# Classic Bluetooth With Unity

Tags: android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am having a hard time trying to make comunication using Android Classic Bluetooth. I have this class in which I grab I have to keep using JavaAndroidObjects, but for some functionalitys like the connect it's not working. Dou you have any other good ideias or ways to make this work?! I can get the information about the bonded devices but only that.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Android;

public class BluetoothService : MonoBehaviour
{
public const int STATE_NONE = 0;
public const int STATE_LISTEN = 1;
public const int STATE_CONNECTING = 2;
public const int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;
const string TAG = "My App";

static readonly string MY_UUID_SECURE = "fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66";

private AndroidJavaObject bluetoothAdapter;
private AcceptThread acceptThread;
private ConnectedThread connectedThread;
public TMP_Text actionDebug;

private int state;
private int newState;

private Timer connectionTimer;
private const int ConnectionCheckInterval = 5000; // Check every 5 seconds
const string SMARTPHONENAME = "Redmi Note 11";

private const string permissionBluetooth = "android.permission.BLUETOOTH";
private const string permissionBluetoothAdmin = "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN";

void Start()
{
    // Request Bluetooth permissions at runtime (if needed)
    if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(permissionBluetooth) ||
        !Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(permissionBluetoothAdmin))
    {
        Permission.RequestUserPermission(permissionBluetooth);
        Permission.RequestUserPermission(permissionBluetoothAdmin);
    }

    StartBluetooth();
    state = STATE_NONE;
    newState = state;
    //connectionTimer = new Timer(CheckConnectionStatus, newState, ConnectionCheckInterval, ConnectionCheckInterval);
}

public void StartBluetooth()
{
    AndroidJavaClass btAdapter = new AndroidJavaClass("android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter");
    bluetoothAdapter = btAdapter.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getDefaultAdapter");
    Debug.Log("BT :" + btAdapter.ToString());

    if (bluetoothAdapter != null && bluetoothAdapter.Call<bool>("isEnabled"))
    {
        AndroidJavaObject pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getBondedDevices");
        AndroidJavaObject[] pairedDeviceArray = pairedDevices.Call<AndroidJavaObject[]>("toArray");
        AndroidJavaObject glasses = pairedDeviceArray.FirstOrDefault(bd => bd.Call<string>("getName") == SMARTPHONENAME);

        Debug.Log("BT :" + pairedDeviceArray);

        if (glasses == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("No connected devices found.");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Found Device: " + glasses.Call<string>("getName"));
            Debug.Log("HELP " + pairedDeviceArray.ToString());
            actionDebug.text = pairedDeviceArray.ToString();
        }

        try
        {

            if (connectedThread != null)
            {
                connectedThread.Cancel();
                connectedThread = null;
            }

            state = STATE_LISTEN;
            UpdateBtStatus();

            Connect(glasses);
            Write(ConvertStringToByteArray());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error connecting to Dorad Glasses: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

public byte[] ConvertStringToByteArray()
{
    // Get the bytes using UTF-8 encoding
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hi from carrier board");

    return byteArray;
}

public void Connect(AndroidJavaObject device)
{
    if (state == STATE_CONNECTING)
    {
        if (connectedThread != null)
        {
            connectedThread.Cancel();
            connectedThread = null;
        }
    }
    // Start the thread to connect with the given device
    ConnectAsync(device);
}

public async void ConnectAsync(AndroidJavaObject device)
{
    AndroidJavaObject socket = null;
    state = STATE_CONNECTING;
    UpdateBtStatus();        

    try
    {
        socket = device.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new AndroidJavaObject("java.util.UUID", MY_UUID_SECURE));

        // Connect asynchronously using AndroidJavaRunnable and AndroidJavaProxy
        var connectRunnable = new AndroidJavaRunnable(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                socket.Call("ConnectAsync");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Failed to connect: " + e.Message);
            }
        });

        var unityPlayerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        var currentActivity = unityPlayerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        currentActivity.Call("runOnUiThread", connectRunnable);

        // Wait for the connection to complete
        await Task.Delay(1000); // Adjust the delay as needed

        if (!socket.Call<bool>("isConnected"))
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to connect");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Close the socket
        try
        {
            socket?.Call("close");
        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            Debug.LogError("unable to close() socket during connection failure: " + e2.Message);
        }

        // Start the service over to restart listening mode
        ConnectionFailed();
        return;
    }
    Connected(socket);
}

public void Stop()
{
    if (acceptThread != null)
    {
        acceptThread.Cancel();
        acceptThread = null;
    }

    if (connectedThread != null)
    {
        connectedThread.Cancel();
        connectedThread = null;
    }

    state = STATE_NONE;
    UpdateBtStatus();
}

//Call this one to send data over BT
public void Write(byte[] data)
{
    if (state != STATE_CONNECTED)
    {
        Debug.LogError("No device connected to send.");
        return;
    }

    if (connectedThread != null)
    {
        connectedThread.Write(data);
    }
}

void UpdateBtStatus()
{
    state = GetState();
    newState = state;
}

void ConnectionFailed()
{
    state = STATE_LISTEN;

    // Handle connection failure
    StartBluetooth();
}

public void Connected(AndroidJavaObject socket)
{
    // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
    if (acceptThread != null)
    {
        acceptThread.Cancel();
        acceptThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (connectedThread != null)
    {
        connectedThread.Cancel();
        connectedThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket, this);
    connectedThread.Start();

    state = STATE_CONNECTED;

    // Handle successful connection
}

void ConnectionLost()
{
    // Handle lost connection
    state = STATE_NONE;
    UpdateBtStatus();
    StartBluetooth();
}

private void CheckConnectionStatus(object state)
{
    // Check the connection status here
    if ((int)state != STATE_CONNECTED)
    {
        ConnectionLost();
    }
}

public int GetState()
{
    // Implement the method to get the Bluetooth connection state
    return STATE_NONE;
}

class ConnectedThread : AndroidJavaProxy
{
    private static readonly string TAG = "ConnectedThread";
    private AndroidJavaObject socket;
    private AndroidJavaObject inStream;
    private AndroidJavaObject outStream;
    private BluetoothService service;

    public ConnectedThread(AndroidJavaObject socket, BluetoothService service) : base("java.lang.Runnable")
    {
        Debug.Log("create ConnectedThread");

        this.socket = socket;
        this.service = service;

        try
        {
            inStream = socket.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getInputStream");
            outStream = socket.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getOutputStream");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to create IO streams: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    bytes = inStream.Call<int>("read", buffer);
                    string receivedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    Debug.Log(receivedData);
                    // Handle received data
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("disconnected: " + e.Message);
                    service.ConnectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //This one does the send
    public void Write(byte[] buffer)
    {
        try
        {
            outStream.Call("write", buffer);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Exception during write: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        try
        {
            socket.Call("close");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("close() of connect socket failed: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am using unity 2021.3.26f1, the android version is the Oreo 8.1 for wearables